# Cannot delete deployment from google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-deployment-manager

I'm trying to create a couple of deployment templates for airflow on GCP / Kubernetes. In that deployment, I seek to deploy all dependent managed services together with some required users and passwords.

I've been able to deploy the services, but it complained about a missing "host" parameter when creating two user. This type is documented here and shouldn't really complain, because host is listed as optional:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/users/insert

So I attempted to delete the deployment, but it's never letting me finish that and it's blocking on the two resources that it can probably never delete now. This is what I get in the console:

```
$ gcloud deployment-manager deployments delete airflow-on-k8s
The following deployments will be deleted:
- airflow-on-k8s

Do you want to continue (y/N)?  y

Waiting for delete [operation-1502140582303-556305bcf9519-0af00aa8-d01c8bf6]...failed.                                                                                       

ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.delete) Delete operation operation-1502140582303-556305bcf9519-0af00aa8-d01c8bf6 failed.
Error in Operation [operation-1502140582303-556305bcf9519-0af00aa8-d01c8bf6]: errors:
- code: RESOURCE_ERROR
location: /deployments/airflow-on-k8s/resources/root-user
message: '{"ResourceType":"sqladmin.v1beta4.user","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"errors":[{"domain":"global","location":"host","locationType":"parameter","message":"Required
parameter: host","reason":"required"}],"message":"Required parameter: host","statusMessage":"Bad
Request","requestPath":"https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/<...>/instances/airflow-db-instance4/users"}}'
- code: RESOURCE_ERROR
location: /deployments/airflow-on-k8s/resources/regular-airflow-user
message: '{"ResourceType":"sqladmin.v1beta4.user","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"errors":[{"domain":"global","location":"host","locationType":"parameter","message":"Required
parameter: host","reason":"required"}],"message":"Required parameter: host","statusMessage":"Bad
Request","requestPath":"https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/<...>/instances/airflow-db-instance4/users"}}'
```

Probably a bug in the API, but if anyone knows of a way, let me know. Also  I heard some googlers hang out on stackoverflow and could potentially forward this to the API developers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had a similar problem deleting my deployment. I ended up deleting the resources by hand, and just abandoned the deployment:

`gcloud deployment-manager deployments delete <deployment name> --delete-policy=ABANDON`

I haven't seen any bugs reported around this, by the way: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=sqladmin.v1beta4.user%20%22Required%20parameter:%20host%22 .

Comment: @Wndrr Correct, the link currently leads to empty search results. This illustrates the fact that a simple search yields no bugs reported around this issue in the Google issue tracker. This seems germane since the OP believed this is "probably a bug in the API".

Comment: hooo, i completly misunderstood. I thought you were pointing to a post saying that this was not a bug. sorry :-)